# Is it possible to use UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer from inside of local service fabric cluster?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.1

I was trying to use UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer option from inside of local service fabric cluster and I got no results. I literally didn't get any requests from server, when I was trying to access SPA application by route `http://localhost:9000/UI/`. I'm using asp.net core 2.1 angular template. I use Razor to create an initial Angular page.

My Startup class looks like:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200/");
            }
        });
    }
```

I'm running application in development mode for sure.
I tried to get any request by launching basic node js server as well as angular app with `ng serve` command, but as I said got no results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I actually figured it out. The problem is `app.UseSpa` is coming after `app.UseMvc`. Since my razor page has been called Index.cshtml, MVC is taking over Spa requests.

Comment: So what should I do? I want to build my client side out of project, but do not load all of my js,css etc.

Comment: @AmirReza-Farahlagha I don't really know, my client side app is part of the .net core projects, so all stuff with building is handled by the framework.